# Issues with UINavigationControllerDelegate and UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have started working with creating custom push/pop transitions and everything is working for the first push transition, but when I try to push another view controller, I get no animation at all.

[Here is a sample project with the code](https://app.box.com/s/csg0hzin2mngd4e4n54578qp28ib2eq8)

Lots of code incoming:

Here is my UINavigationControllerDelegate class:

```
@interface CKMNavigationControllerDelegate : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

- (instancetype)initWithForwardTransitionObject:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)inForwardTransitionObject popTransitionObject:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)inBackTransitionObject;

@property(nonatomic, strong) id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning> forwardTransitionObject;
@property(nonatomic, strong) id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning> backTransitionObject;

@end

@implementation CKMNavigationControllerDelegate

- (instancetype)initWithForwardTransitionObject:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)inForwardTransitionObject popTransitionObject:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)inBackTransitionObject
{
    NSAssert( [inForwardTransitionObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning)], @"inForwardTransitionObject does not conform to protocol UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning" );
    NSAssert( [inBackTransitionObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning)], @"inBackTransitionObject does not conform to protocol UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning" );

    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    _forwardTransitionObject = inForwardTransitionObject;
    _backTransitionObject = inBackTransitionObject;

    return self;
}

- (void)setForwardTransitionObject:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)inForwardTransitionObject
{
    NSAssert( [inForwardTransitionObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning)], @"inForwardTransitionObject does not conform to protocol UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning" );
    _forwardTransitionObject = inForwardTransitionObject;
}

- (void)setBackTransitionObject:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)inBackTransitionObject
{
    NSAssert( [inBackTransitionObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning)], @"inBackTransitionObject does not conform to protocol UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning" );
    _backTransitionObject = inBackTransitionObject;
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)inNavigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)inOperation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)inFroViewController toViewController:(UIViewController *)inToViewController
{
    return  inOperation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush ? self.forwardTransitionObject : self.backTransitionObject;
}
```

My class that implements UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning for push transitions:

```
@interface CKMForwardTransitionObject : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@end

@implementation CKMForwardTransitionObject

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    NSAssert([toViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CKMTransitionAnimatable)], @"toViewController does not conform to CKMTransitionAnimatable");
    NSAssert([fromViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CKMTransitionAnimatable)], @"fromViewController does not conform to CKMTransitionAnimatable");

    id <CKMTransitionAnimatable> fromAnimationSource = (id <CKMTransitionAnimatable>)fromViewController;
    id <CKMTransitionAnimatable> toAnimationSource = (id <CKMTransitionAnimatable>)toViewController;

    CGFloat duration = [fromAnimationSource transitionOutDuration] + [toAnimationSource transitionInDuration];

    return duration;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    NSAssert([toViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CKMTransitionAnimatable)], @"toViewController does not conform to CKMTransitionAnimatable");
    NSAssert([fromViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CKMTransitionAnimatable)], @"fromViewController does not conform to CKMTransitionAnimatable");

    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
    [containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];

    id <CKMTransitionAnimatable> fromAnimationSource = (id <CKMTransitionAnimatable>)fromViewController;
    id <CKMTransitionAnimatable> toAnimationSource = (id <CKMTransitionAnimatable>)toViewController;


    CGFloat animationDelay = [fromAnimationSource transitionOutDuration];
    [fromAnimationSource animateOnTransitionOut:nil];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(animationDelay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [toAnimationSource animateOnTransitionIn:^{
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
    });

}
```

My protocol that ViewControllers using custom transitions will implement:

```
typedef void (^CKMAnimationCompletionBlock)(void);

@protocol CKMTransitionAnimatable <NSObject>

- (void)animateOnTransitionIn:(CKMAnimationCompletionBlock)inAnimationCompletionBlock;
- (void)animateOnTransitionOut:(CKMAnimationCompletionBlock)inAnimationCompletionBlock;
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionInDuration;
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionOutDuration;

@end
```

And finally the code in the view controller that actually implements the CKMTransitionAnimatable protocol:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionInDuration
{
    return 0.4;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionOutDuration
{
    return 0.4;
}

- (void)animateOnTransitionOut:(CKMAnimationCompletionBlock)inAnimationCompletionBlock
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionOutDuration] animations:^{
        self.contentView.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if( inAnimationCompletionBlock )
        {
            inAnimationCompletionBlock();
        }
    }];
}

- (void)animateOnTransitionIn:(CKMAnimationCompletionBlock)inAnimationCompletionBlock
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionInDuration] animations:^{
        self.contentView.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if( inAnimationCompletionBlock )
        {
            inAnimationCompletionBlock();
        }
    }];
}
```

Everything looks pretty straightforward, but for the life of me, I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue...looks like it was the way I was adding the view controllers to the container view in animateTransition. It should look like this:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    NSAssert([toViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CKMTransitionAnimatable)], @"toViewController does not conform to CKMTransitionAnimatable");
    NSAssert([fromViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CKMTransitionAnimatable)], @"fromViewController does not conform to CKMTransitionAnimatable");

    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    [containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];


    id <CKMTransitionAnimatable> fromAnimationSource = (id <CKMTransitionAnimatable>)fromViewController;
    id <CKMTransitionAnimatable> toAnimationSource = (id <CKMTransitionAnimatable>)toViewController;

    [fromAnimationSource animateOnTransitionOut:nil];
    CGFloat animationDelay = [fromAnimationSource transitionOutDuration];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(animationDelay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
        [toAnimationSource animateOnTransitionIn:^{
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
    });

}
```